# Попытка настроить uwsgi + flask

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, uwsgi

установил uwsgi, пытаюсь его запустить со своим приложением на фласке (само приложение работает) 
ловлю ошибку:

```
    -ThinkPad-Edge-E440:~/image-processor$ uwsgi --pythonpath /image-rocessor/src 
--http :9090 --thunder-lock --master --enable-threads --wsgi-file wsgi.py
 --callable=app --gevent 400


*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Tue Oct  2 16:01:46 2018] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 02 October 2018 08:14:02
os: Linux-4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:25:58 UTC 2018
nodename: ubuntu-ThinkPad-Edge-E440
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/image-processor
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/uWSGI/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 30574
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
- async cores set to 400 - fd table size: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: enabled
uWSGI http bound on :9090 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:40955 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x130eb60
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 8476928 bytes (8278 KB) for 400 cores
*** Operational MODE: async ***
added /image-processor/src to pythonpath.
failed to open python file wsgi.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 4057)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 4058, cores: 400)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 4059)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x48a8e0] ***
```

без понятия, как это исправить, перепробовал кучу всего просто

Comment: А запускаете в докере?

Comment: Ничего не понимаю в uwsgi, но что будет, если вместо `--pythonpath /image-processor/src` указать `--pythonpath ~/image-processor/src`, `--pythonpath image-processor/src` или даже `--pythonpath /home/ubuntu/image-processor/src`?

Comment: pythonpath, это параметр из gunicorn,  я был уверен, что он работает и в uwsgi...

Answer (score 0):

Решение заключается в том, чтобы заменить --pythonpath на --chdir

И всё.